# Are there marking standards for FFC Cables?

Tags: ffc

I tried replacing a no-brand FFC cable marked "AWM 20624 80C 60V VW-1" with a 3 times longer one from WE marked "AWM 20706 105C 60V VW-1". It's not working, and I'm faulting length.

However is it possible those are two different cable standards and that is interfering with the signal propagation? I'm guessing not, since that I didn't find any such information in the cable datasheet, but I still find it worth asking. Thank you.

Comment: You need to tell us about what is passing over the cable.

Comment: A high frequency nightmare, RGB parallel data at 75MHz. Yeah, I guess I will need to stick with the shorter cable. Sorry for asking this question, I should have given up before even thinking of trying.

Comment: Well, it is possible the characteristic impedances of the cables are different, and that's causing trouble, but length is the likely problem.